# How to remove undefined array in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

- I am trying to select folder content
- In that folder contain images when I am select that folder it will select all content.
- plus it is taking img src undefind
- so I need to remove that how can I remove if src is undefined using asp.net c#

  ```
  <div id="cell" class="box2">
       <a href="undefined">
          <img width="260px" height="135px" src="undefined"
               alt="" 
               style="box-shadow: 1px    2px 2px #BDBDBD;
              border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;">
         </img>
       </a>
  </div>
  ```

**Code behind file:**

```
protected void chbindustry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (result == false)
            {

                string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(Server.MapPath("BusinessCards"));
                string f;
                string[] ss;
                string side = chklist.SelectedValue;// RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
                foreach (ListItem li in chbindustry.Items)
                {
                    if (li.Selected)
                    {

                        ss = li.Text.Split('(');

                        f = Server.MapPath("BusinessCards").ToString() + "\\" + ss[0];
                        int c = f.Count();
                        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(f);
                        int len = d.GetFiles().Length;
                        for (int i = 1; i <= d.GetFiles().Length / 3; i++)
                        {
                            Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("ImgPaths", "'" + "BusinessCards/" + f.Remove(0, f.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1) + "/" + i + ".jpg'");
                            Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("refs", "'" + "DesignBCs.aspx?img=BusinessCards/" + f.Remove(0, f.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1) + "/" + i + "&Side=" + side + "'");
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            result = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of the image src values in C#, you could use LINQ to filter out any of them that are undefined:

```
var list = some code to get a list of img srcs from your folder;
list = list.Where(value => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(value)).ToList();
```

The lambda `value => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(value)` filters `list` such that each element is not null or whitespace (what I'm assuming you mean by undefined).

Does this help?  If you can share some sample code of what you have now we can help more.

Comment: <a href="undefined">
        <img width="260px" height="135px" src="undefined" alt="" style="box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #BDBDBD; border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;"></img>
    </a>

</div>

Comment: Can you also share the ASP.NET code that generated that?

Comment: Can you debug that code behind and post what `subdirectoryEntries`, `ss`, `f`, and `len` are?  Also, why are you dividing by 3 in your for loop?

Comment: i have img folder in my pc its fetching img from that folder and in loop divide by 3 means in each row create 3 imgs k. when i select folder in that folder contain 5 image 1st row fill wit 3 img and 2nd row only fill 2 img one img box is empty so i need to remove that